# Is there anyway to add the eating time

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I'm doing a Minecraft map and I'm trying to do a medkit. My plan is that when a player eats a steak they will get a X amount of health. But it would pretty OP if you could take a medkit in 3 sec. So is there anyway to do so it takes longer for the player to eat the steak. Ohh, and by the way I'm using those command blocks to detect that the player has eaten the steak.

```
/scoreboard objectives add NAME stat.useItem.minecraft.cooked_beef 
/effect @a[score_steak_min=1] minecraft:jump_boost 10 5
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Should they not have the item before the timer ends (easy solution, but not intuitive)? Should the eating have no effect, meaning they waste the item (easy, but possibly unfair)? Should the effect be delayed (a bit harder, possible to stack the effect)? Also, how do you want to indicate to the player that they can't use it right now?

Comment: @Fabian It sounds like he wants to emulate PUBG, where using a medkit to restore health takes a few seconds before you actually get the health back and therefore carries some minor risk (since you can't defend yourself while applying the medkit). I think he just wants the eating animation to take longer than it currently does.

Comment: Yea! Exactly what i wanted!. Is there any possible way to do so that the animation takes longer?

Comment: Would requiring more then one steak work for you?  Or could you compensate by adding a short slowness effect as part of the medkit?  Instead of attempting to make the eating duration longer, is there some other solution that would work for you?

Comment: Hmm. I will work on it! But thanks anyway guys! :D. I will update this post if i find any answers

Comment: If you find an answer to your question, you are allowed/encouraged to answer your own question on Arqade.  There is a page in the help center about this: [Can I answer my own question?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)